# Form can't assign to function call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Flight funtion doesn't return from models in view. I changed models from null=True to nothing. Is the problem within my return code or is it something else? The thing is nothing gives an error other than views which is weird.

```
def add_flight(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = FlightForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                a = Flight(departing_date=form.cleaned_data["departing_date"],
                      deptAirport=form.cleaned_data["deptAirport"],
                      arrAirport=form.cleaned_data["arrAirport"],
                      duration=form.cleaned_data["departing_date"],
                      airline=form.cleaned_data["airline"],
                      price=form.cleaned_data["price"],
                      deptCity=form.cleaned_data["deptCity"],
                      arrCity=form.cleaned_data["arrCity"],
                      deptHour=form.cleaned_data["deptHour"],                       ,
                      arrHour=form.cleaned_data["arrHour"])
                a.save()
                #return HttpResponse("Success!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/flights/')
        else:
            form = FlightForm()
    
        return render(request, 'add_flight.html', {'form': form})
```

It can't return Flight model from models which looks like this

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    departing_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    deptAirport = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrAirport = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    airline = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    deptCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    arrCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    deptHour = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    arrHour = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.departing_date+" "+self.deptAirport+" "+self.arrAirport+" "+self.duration+" "\
               +self.airline+" "+self.price+" "+self.deptCity+" "+self.arrCity+" "+self.deptHour+" "+self.arrHour
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why dont you just use `form.save()` if it is valid?

Comment: @PacketLoss Thanks the server worked but it still says 'FlightForm' object has no attribute 'save' what do you think that is?

Comment: `if form.is_valid(): form.save()`

Comment: Is the `FlightForm` is a [Django model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) ?

Comment: @JPG I turned it into a Modelform but now it says day is out of range for month but i have a date field that you can enter anything.